# Laravel - Eloquent Query not giving expected result

Tags: mysql, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I have this code:

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employees';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    ];


    public function leaverequest()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Hr\Goal');
    }
}
```

```
class Goal extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'goals';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'employee_id',
        'is_published',
        'company_id',
    ];

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\Employee', 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

I want to count the number of employees that have published  their goals and groupby `employee_id` where `is_published` is 1.

```
$testing = Goal::where('is_published', 1)
       ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
       ->groupBy('employee_id')
       ->count();
```

From the table I have four (4) rows but the same `employee_id`, I expected to get 1 but I am getting 4?

dd($testing) gives me 4

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `$testing = Goal::where('is_published', 1)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->distinct('employee_id')->count();` or `$testing = Goal::where('is_published', 1)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->groupBy('employee_id')->get()->count();`

Comment: This $testing = Goal::where('is_published', 1)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->distinct('employee_id')->count();     still gives the former result   while the other one gives error

Comment: There's 2 groupbys in laravel. One for the Querybuilder and one for the collection class. You can try to use the collection to see if it gives better results: `$testing = count(Goal::where('is_published', 1)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->get()->groupBy('employee_id'));`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the combination of `count` with `distinct`

Query is something like this;

```
select count(distinct employee_id) as total
from goals 
where is_published = 1 and company_id = 1;
```

Eloquent way;

```
$testing = Goal::where('is_published', 1)
            ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
            ->first([
                DB::raw('count(distinct employee_id) as total')
            ])
            ->total;
```